# C++/MFC is there a way to click a button while clicking another one?

Tags: c++, button, mfc

I have 2 buttons in my projects :

-Button A

-Button B

Is there a way i can push the buttonA and perform the click of ButtonB aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the answer was accepted, I would like to offer another solution.

First, the proposed linking of buttons will break as soon as you decide that clicking on ButtonB should cause click on ButtonA too.

I would separate all that clicking from the underlying functionality, and invoke it as needed:

```
void MyDialog::Button_A_Action()
{
}

void MyDialog::Button_B_Action()
{
}

void MyDialog::OnButton_A_Clicked()
{
  Button_A_Action();
  Button_B_Action();
}

void MyDialog::OnButton_B_Clicked()
{
  Button_B_Action();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

<del>Call the callback for ButtonB explicitly from ButtonA click callback.</del>

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnButton_A_Clicked()
{
  ...
  OnButton_B_Clicked();
}
```

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650880/c-mfc-is-there-a-way-to-click-a-button-while-clicking-another-one/35650989#comment58987034_35650989), calling a handler directly may cause subtle problems, I would propose the following solution from the same comment:

Send button click message to the button B.

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnButton_A_Clicked()
{
  ...
  CWnd *pBtnB = GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTONB);
  ASSERT(pBtnB != NULL);  // You can use MFC 
  pBtnB->SendMessage(BN_CLICKED);
}
```

Comment: While this may work as expected, I've seen instances where directly calling a handler from within another handler may cause some subtle problems.  I would prefer to post/send the appropriate message to avoid any potential issues.

Comment: @rrirower Thanks for your comment. I have edited my answer. Can you please tell what possible problems can occur if you call a handler from another?

Comment: It really depends upon what the original event handler is doing.  Typically, I've seen window handles and other objects suddenly become invalid because the original message was not completely processed when the next nested handler was called.

Comment: @rrirower Thanks for the quick response. I didn't completely understand this completely, and will try to investigate more. In the mean time if you come across a good link or section from book, please post.

Comment: rriower is the one who made the suggestion, but I'm the one who downvoted your answer. Now removed. :-) Calling the event handler directly is just bad design. It makes the code difficult to understand and increases coupling/decreases encapsulation. Also, while it might work fine for something as simple as a button click that passes along no additional information, it is often hard to concoct the necessary parameters that certain event handlers expect. Finally, it can subtly break in unexpected ways. You may know that when a window message is sent, there is a keyboard state, a mouse...

Comment: pointer position, and all kinds of other state that is stored for you by the window manager. If the event handler were to retrieve this information (e.g., by calling `GetKeyState`, `GetMessagePos`, etc.), it would get the wrong information because the event handler was not called in response to a message!

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks a lot. I was searching this all over and got similar info. But I must say you have summarized it beautifully in the comment. Now I understand it completely why my first answer was bad.

Comment: Use PostMessage if there is any concern.